# Mockito: Difference between TestStub and Mock

Tags: java, mockito

I know that teststubs in mockito are just for control the inputs and outputs of the test doubles

Mocks in contrast to that have to verify the method call which is crucial for the test

Lets say we want to test the `sendMessage`()-method:

```
public void sendMessage(Client client,Template template) {
         String msgContent=templateEngine.prepareMessage(template,client);
         mailserver.send(client.getEmail(),msgContent); 
}
```

Now my question:

The `mailserver.send`()-method is crucial for `sendMessage` and have to be verified as a mock. Thats ok for me. But why the `templateEngine.prepareMessage()` should be designed as teststub? I know that we only need the `msgContent`-object as a parameter for `mailserver.send()`, but shouldnt do I also verify that the `perepareMessage()`-method is invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One test should focus on one thing. The method is about sending, so the test should verify that.

If you take the message-preparation into the verification, you have bound those two together. When you now refactor the code to have the message-prep in another method you have to change the tests, although nothing changed about the sending part.

BTW: if something goes wrong along the way, `send()` wont get executed and the test is red.